# How reliable is dc.GetDeviceCaps(PHYSICALOFFSETX)?

Tags: winapi, printing, mfc, gdi

I'm getting wrong values in some printers.

For example, `dc.GetDeviceCaps(PHYSICALOFFSETX)` returns 42 in some printer and `LOGPIXELSX` is 360, so the left margin should be 2.96 millimeters, but actually test shows that is 5 millimeters !

PD: `PHYSICALOFFSETY` works fine!

Comment: Did you measure from the edge of a font or line? The font may have its own gap. Either way 2 millimeters is a good margin of error.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the printer and the driver, and possibly on how you load the paper.  For example, on a lot of tractor-feed (e.g., dot-matrix) printers, there's a lot of horizontal play, and it's up to the user to load the paper correctly.

The other problem I've seen is that some printer drivers forget to swap the reported horizontal and vertical offsets and resolutions when you switch the page orientation (landscape/portrait) in the middle of a job.  But that's pretty easy to detect and correct for.

Software that's supposed to print data in pre-drawn boxes on forms (e.g., invoices, checks, etc.) generally has an interactive alignment process to allow the user to make adjustments to compensate for printer error, paper loading error, etc.